# Android AVD Won't Display Multiple Panes

Tags: android

I'm learning about multi-pane apps and am running the Master/Detail Flow application that gets set up by Android Studio when you create a new project (and select this option). According to the comments within the Google code that gets created, the app should display in multi-pane mode for devices with large-screen layouts. The problem that I am having is that no matter what AVD I use, I only get a single pane. First, here is the onCreate method of the main activity. Please note that this code comes straight from Google (it isn't my code):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

        if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
            // The detail container view will be present only in the
            // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
            // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
            // activity should be in two-pane mode.
            mTwoPane = true;

            // In two-pane mode, list items should be given the
            // 'activated' state when touched.
            ((ItemListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.item_list))
                    .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
        }

        // TODO: If exposing deep links into your app, handle intents here.
    }
```

According to the [Android Developer docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), running this code on a device with dp of at least 640dp x 480dp is large enough to qualify as a large screen, and presumably will then render in multi-pane mode. I'm using an AVD to model the Nexus 10 API 19 device, which has 800dp x 1280: xhdpi. Here is more information:
[image]

Here is what I get when I run this. Clearly not displaying multiple panes:
[image]
What do I need to do to get this to show multiple panes? When I run this on a USB-connected device, it works perfectly, so the code is accurate. The issue must be the AVD that I am using? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem : edit your AVD, go to advanced settings, then select no skin in the "Custom skin definition" combo box.