# android incorrect layout for tablet in setContentView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on a toy app which has different layout files for phones and tablets but in tablet mode it doesn't use the correct layout in `layout-sw600dp` folder. Here are my files contents:

`activity_main.xml` in `layout-sw600dp` folder:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity">

    <!--
    This layout is a two-pane layout for the Items master/detail flow.
    -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_forecast"
        android:name="com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/weather_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`activity_main.xml` in `layout` folder:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_forecast"
    android:name="com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
```

`onCreate` method in `MainActivity.java`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mLocation = Utility.getPreferredLocation(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(findViewById(R.id.weather_detail_container) != null)
    {
        mTwoPane = true;

        if(savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.weather_detail_container, new DetailActivityFragment(),DETAILFRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mTwoPane = false;
    }
}
```

I'm using `emulated Nexus 10` to test the app. When the app comes up it shows the single pane layout, the same as phone view. I don't know what is going wrong here.

I also tried with `emulated Nexus 7` and still the problem exists.

Amazingly I tried with `Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 API 16 real device` and the layout works perfectly. Is there any issue with the emulated device that causes the problem?

**EDIT**

I suspected that there is something wrong with emulated device and tried to `emulate Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 API 16`. The layout works fine on the emulated version of the device too.

I tried to also use `API 16` with `emulated Nexus 7` but still I got the single pane layout. Is there something wrong with `Nexus 7 & 10` with `layout-sw600dp` folder?

Comment: have you tried sw720dp?

Comment: Nexus 10 uses layout-sw720dp folder. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556800/layout-folders-for-google-nexus-7-and-10) is more details.

Comment: @gj_ yes I have tried, the same problem

Comment: @VladimirJovanović as the name suggests it is the smallest width and since nexus 10 falls in the category, it should display it. Anyway i tried with sw720 and no luck

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the issue with emulator.

Straight solution - don't use Nexus skin.

I tested various configs: Nexus 9 should work fine.

Almost in all Android courses (topic: fragments, two pane mode) in forums you can find complains about this issue.

SO questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461645/android-avd-wont-display-multiple-panes), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832188/tablet-ui-doesnt-work-on-my-app).

There are some questions in the android issue tracker: [1](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=95861&q=tablet%20two&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened), [2](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191296&q=tablet&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened).

The issue is old and there is no official responses.

Comment: can you share some references to prove this?

Comment: Had the same issue ...empirically... You can test it by yourself.

Comment: if you read my "EDIT" section, I mentioned with some devices it works and with others it doesn't, I'm actually looking for the reason of that

Comment: Did you try same configurations but without Nexus skin?

Comment: I don't remember as this was quite while ago but will test and let you know

Comment: IMO this a very good tutorial and I often encounter some good challenges when reading through it which I haven't encountered before when developing other programs

Comment: apparently it is the nexus skin for 7 & 10 that causes the problem, have you found any documentations regarding this?